# Kolsch fermentation temps and schedule

Tags: beer, fermentation-temperature, beer-styles

I'm brewing a Kolsch beer for the first time with a pretty straight forward recipe using WLP029 yeast. I've only brewed basic ales so far and I'm confused about the fermentation temps and times for this style. From what I read on the White Labs site this yeast is not successful below 62f, but from what I understand Kolsch style should be lagered. Should I treat it as a lager and primary ferment at 62f until it's 75% complete and then move to a secondary and lager it for several weeks at 50f or so? Or should I just keep it at 62f for primary and secondary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ferment at the recommended temperature until terminal gravity is achieved, and then lager at near freezing temperature. If you bring the temp down to 50 F. Before terminal gravity is reached the mostly likely outcome is a stalled fermentation.